# R - Using xgboost as feature selection but also interaction selection

Tags: r, xgboost, feature-selection, interaction, variable-selection

Let's say I have a dataset with a lot of variables (more than in the reproductible example below) and I want to build a simple and interpretable model, a GLM.

I can use a **xgboost** model first, and look at **importance of variables** (which depends on the frequency and the gain of each variable in the successive decision trees) to select the 10 most influent variables:

**Question** : is there a way to highlight the most significant 2d-interactions ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(xgboost)

# data
data(mtcars)
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(
  data  = mtcars %>% select(-am) %>% as.matrix(), 
  label = mtcars$am
)

# xgboost parameters
xgb_params <- list(
  objective = "binary:logistic",
  eta       = 0.1,
  max_depth = 2
)

# xgboost fit
xgb_mod <- xgb.train(
  data     = dtrain, 
  params   = xgb_params,   
  nrounds  = 10,
  eval     = "auc",
  maximize = TRUE   
)

# feature importance
xgb.importance(dimnames(dtrain)[[2]], model = xgb_mod)
#    Feature       Gain      Cover  Frequency
# 1:      wt 0.53965838 0.46589322 0.47619048
# 2:    gear 0.41691383 0.37360220 0.28571429
# 3:    qsec 0.03215627 0.11810252 0.19047619
# 4:      hp 0.01127152 0.04240205 0.04761905
```

**Question** : is there a way to highlight the most significant interaction according to the xgboost model ?

According to the feature importance, I can built a GLM with 4 variables (`wt`, `gear`, `qsec`, `hp`) but I would like to know if some 2d-interaction (for instance `wt:hp`) should have an interest to be added in a simple model.

Comment: Have you looked at [Xgbfi](https://github.com/Far0n/xgbfi)?

Comment: I am trying to install the package, without success for now. `install_github("Far0n/xgbfi")` didn't work, I download the zip but something failing when I tried to make the installation : `* checking for file 'xgbfi/DESCRIPTION' ... NO`

Comment: I managed to install RXGfi `devtools::install_github("RSimran/RXGBfi")`, but I got the same error than here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686063/xgb-fi-function-detecting-interactions-and-working-with-xgboost-returns-except